# How do I pdfgrep using a specific pattern (Syntax?)

Tags: regular-expression, pdfgrep

I'm trying to use pdfgrep to search each occurences of a specific pattern (MUST start with E OR S) then followed by 5 digits (Only) THEN execute a command afterward (Which is likely to be a mv command)

So far, I have the following command :

```
pdfgrep -e '[E-S]\d{5,}$' filename.pdf
```

But for the life of me, I am unable to find anything in that PDF. Searching for a specific term (pdfgrep "term" filename.pdf) does return the term in question so I know pdfgrep is able to find it.

I am guessing my issue is the syntax of the command or regex but I cannot find where exactly...

Comment: I don't have pdfgrep to check, but does this work as expected `pdfgrep  -E '[ES][0-9]{5,}$' filename.pdf`?

Comment: Strangely enough, yes it works. I figured I could replace [0-9]{5,} with \d{5,} but it doesn't work with this syntax.

Comment: There are many different flavors of regular expressions. Grep and, presumably, pdfgrep default to basic regular expressions (BRE). The `\d` comes from Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (I think) and is also supported in at least some versions of extended regular expressions (ERE). But see my answer, you also had another couple of issues.

Answer (score 3):

You have three issues here. First, the character class `[E-S]` means "match every character *from* E *to* S". To just match `E` or `S`, use `[ES]`.

Next, the `{x,y}` format to set the number of repetitions isn't supported in BRE (basic regular expressions) and neither is `\d`, so you need to enable PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) with the `-P` flag. This will let you use `\d` for "digits" (you would need `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` in BRE) as well as the `{x,y}`. Finally, `{5,}` would mean "5 or more", to get exactly 5 you need `{5}`.

So, putting all this together, the command you are looking for is:

```
pdfgrep  -P '[ES]\d{5}$'
```